# Azure SFTP Logic App

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App that monitors an SFTP site for new files, and if it finds one, it sends a message to an Azure Queue for subsequent processing, then deletes the file. My application has grown in scale and a single logic app seems to only be grabbing 5-10 files a minute.

Is it possible to setup a second (third, fourth, etc.) Logic App that monitors the same SFTP site, without the two apps conflicting/colliding with each other. I also see that there is a "High Throughput" setting that seems interesting, but I'm not sure it is what I need. My ultimate goal is to process more files faster, and I am considering changing the Logic App out for a scheduled Web Job that monitors the SFTP site. Since I am live and files are pouring in, I am a little reluctant to change anything until I know it's safe.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you considered incorporating Service Bus to your LA?

Comment: Hi, Mike. Thanks for the help. I said "Azure Queue" in my post, but it is in fact an Azure Service Bus with a dedicated that the LA writes to when it finds a file. That portion is fine, it just seems very slow at polling the SFTP site. What were you thinking as to how a SB can be used to increase throughput? I am also finding that after SFTP site contains more than 31K files, it seems to no longer detect new file additions to the SFTP site. I imagine it is caching a Last Polled Date and comparing to the current files in the folder that are newer, so maybe it is timing out (the LA internally)?

Answer (score 0):

Logic app comes under server less architecture, IF we select the pricing model based on 'number of executions' then it impact on the performance since Microsoft allocates the resources for such kind of pricing model as shared one and which server is free up the processing. I would recommend to attache service plan to it and select the pricing model 'per minute'

One more point, If you want longer operations to be done then Azure logic app is not appropriate one but since you are connecting to enterprise integration then logic app is good choice. I would recommend to divide this functionality between logic app with Azure function OR Microsoft flow.